# Json Parsing to T[] object in Unity3D Using JsonUtility always return null

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

So, here is my Json String that I want to tried to parse into array in my Unity code

```
[
{"id":1,"museum":"Museum Kelvin"}
,{"id":2,"museum":"Museum Keke"},
{"id":3,"museum":"Museum Keke2"},
{"id":4,"museum":"Museum Keke2"}
]
```

I already get the value of this string by using this code

```
 IEnumerator GetPertanyaan()
    {
        string getPertanyaanUrl = "http://museumadv.azurewebsites.net/museum/list";
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(getPertanyaanUrl,"1"))
        {
            //www.chunkedTransfer = false;
            yield return www.Send();
            if (www.isError || www.responseCode==500 || www.responseCode==404)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.responseCode);
            }
            else
            {
                if (www.isDone)
                {
                    string jsonResult =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
                    Debug.Log(jsonResult); // Succes to read the JSON 


                    JMuseum[] entities = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<JMuseum>(jsonResult);


                    foreach (var pert in entities)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(pert.museum); //always null
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The Json Helper Class

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] getJsonArray<T>(string json)
    {
        string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(newJson);
        return wrapper.array;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] array;
    }
}
```

and my model class for JMuseum

```
[System.Serializable]
public class JMuseum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string museum { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is, the value of the museum always empty (null), but the length of the array is correct.

Do you guys have any solution to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unity can not serialize properties.

Try this

```
public class JMuseum
{
    public int id;
    public string museum;
}
```

Comment: I set up a minimal example from your code and got it working just by this change..

Comment: thank you, I see my problems now :) thank you for answering :)